# MongoDB not getting delete request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

CLIENT:

```
 const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete`, {id})
      .then(res => console.log(err)})
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

CONSOLE LOGS THE ID correctly: vv17OZpdGkMwNEv0

SERVER:

```
cartRoutes.route("/delete").delete((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("cart");
  let myquery = { id: req.body.id };
  db_connect.collection("cart").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // console.log("1 document deleted");
  });
});
```

CONSOLE LOGS OUT {}

This is basically copied from MongoDB document, the server(2nd block of code) does not recognize the call from the client. I know that the mongo code works because if I manually put the id in the 'myquery' variable, the item is deleted in the database
Why is that? MongoDB doc has it set up like below which I've tried and still the req.body returns '{}'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, not sure if using params is the correct way/best practice

Client

```
  const handleDelete = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete/${id}`)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Server

```
cartRoutes.route("/delete/:id").delete((req, res) => {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("cart");
  let myquery = { id: res.req.params.id };
  db_connect.collection("cart").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // console.log("1 document deleted");
  });
});
```

Comment: For deletion, including userId in **pathparam** is ok.

Comment: Better you try the following to fetch the userId from request body. `axios.delete(url, { data: { id: id } });`

For more info: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897